# How to submit a form as well as execute a javascript function in clicking an input button?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, forms, dom

This code works, but it shows the heading only for an instant, How we can execute an sql query as well as javascript function to change the innerHTML on a form submission.

**//HTML**

```
<div id='heading'> </div>
```

**//form**

```
<form method='post'>
<input type='submit name='option' value='option' onclick='myFunction()' > 
</form>
```

**//sql query**

```
if(isset($_POST['option'])===true && empty($_POST['option']===true)){
                $sql2= 'SELECT * from maptable ORDER by price';
                $result = $mysql->query($sql2);

  }
```

**//javascript function**

```
 <script>
    function myFunction(){
     document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML ='OptionName';
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you use AJAX for server side execution?

Comment: No, It is basic javascript

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, You want to call the function before the PHP code is executed.
Just change `onclick="myFunction()"` to `onsubmit= "return myFunction()"`.

It's also a good practice to surrond your `document.getElemen....` with a try catch block.

Comment: You don't need to wrap `getElementById` with try/catch. If you are truly concerned it didn't pull an element, just grab the element in a variable and test it with `if (el)`. In this case, `#heading` will always exist.

Comment: Still the same problem, What does return do though?

Comment: @SomeShinyObject Sorry I didn't get that.

Comment: @SomeShinyObject Probably Your idea is better when we have one or two calls as we have here :)

Comment: @PrabhjotKaur My Mistake, change ````onclick```` to ````onsubmit````

Answer (score 0):

The way you are executing this at the moment isn't going to work. You are posting directly to the same page with your form without AJAX which means the page refreshes. Since JavaScript is client side, it's not going to persist your heading's `innerHTML` that you set. There are a million and one ways to fix this.

The quickest way to "fix" this is declare what you want the heading to be in your PHP processing and then output that in the H1 element if it exists:

```
#PHP
if(isset($_POST['option'])===true && empty($_POST['option']===true)){
    $sql2= 'SELECT * from maptable ORDER by price';
    $result = $mysql->query($sql2);
    // Depending on what you want your Heading to be
    // $headingName = $_POST['option'];
    $headingName = "OptionName";
}
```

Set your HTML heading like so:

```
<div id='heading'><?php echo isset($headingName) ? $headingName : '' ?></div>
```

Also, your input is missing a quotation, and with this change, you don't need the JavaScript portion anymore:

```
<input type='submit' name='option' value='option'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='submit name='option'
```

Look at your code here. You skip a quote It should be like this `<input type='submit' name='option'`

As I see your form submitting without AJAX, so once you click "submit" button, the page will be reloaded and return a result of PHP script execution.

If you want to run your "myFunction" before submitting you can do this:

```
<form id="myForm">
  ...
</form>

<input type='button' name='option' onclick="myFunction()">
```

**And "myFunction":**

```
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML ='OptionName';
    document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
}
```

OR, if you want the "heading" div to be shown some time, you can submit the form using timeout:

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = 'OptionName';
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
  }, <timeout of submitting in milliseconds>);
}
```